# Is it possible to avoid installing magisk bootloop protector module on Magisk?

Tags: magisk

I am using Pixel 8 with Android 14.0 (UD1A.230803.041), with Magisk Delta Canary version(0fe46c5a-delta, 26301).

The problem is that Magisk Bootloop Protector module causes my phone to crash. The only way to prevent crashing is to remove (not disable) the module, but it gets installed every boot without any prompt or user intervention, so I have to remove that every time I have to reboot the phone.

That's not much to bother, it's not like it's impossible to remove,
but sometimes removing the Magisk Bootloop Protector causes all of the other module to be disabled, requiring to be enabled *and* reboot the phone. Yes, rebooting the phone would automatically install Magisk Bootloop Protector to be installed again, so I have to remove that - sometimes this loops so I have to reboot again, remove the module again, so on...

Is there any way to disable installing the module, or am I out of luck?

P.S. Even with no other modules installed at all, I found that this module was causing the crash, so I think other modules are irrelevant to this question. I've already tested.

Comment: (I hope this question is on-topic, but please let me know if it's not. )

Answer (score 0):

In the Magisk documentation if you have problems with Magisk modules that cause boot-loops you can put your phone into safe mode and that can disable all modules so you can remove the module causing problems then reboot normally.

Comment: Thank you for reading my question. I've already read and done that. Now you do the same, read my question.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is possible to avoid installing the Magisk bootloop protector module on Magisk. The bootloop protector module, also known as "init.d scripts," is designed to help prevent bootloops on your device by running certain scripts during startup. However, if you prefer not to use it, you can simply avoid installing this module in Magisk.

To do so, follow these steps:

Open the Magisk Manager app on your rooted device.

Tap on the "Modules" section in the app.

Look for the "Magisk bootloop protector" module in the list of available modules. If you haven't installed it, you won't find it in this list.

If you find the module and want to avoid installing it, simply don't select or install it. You can choose to skip this module during the installation process.

If you have already installed the module and want to remove it, go to the "Modules" section, find the "Magisk bootloop protector" module, and tap on it. Then, select the option to uninstall the module.

By following these steps, you can avoid installing or remove the Magisk bootloop protector module if you don't want to use it. This will not affect the functioning of Magisk itself, but it may affect how your device handles certain scripts during startup.

Comment: Welcome to the Q&A site Android Enthusiast Stack Exchange. Could you mention the source or reference to back this answer up?